# $\ell_\infty$ partially enclosing ball problem

Tags: computational-geometry

Suppose I have $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ endowed with the $\ell_\infty$ metric, and I wish to find a minimum-diameter ball that contains some $k$ of these points. What is known about this problem? Easy/hard? Approximations? Heuristics?

Comment: I suspect this is hard. This paper has an algorithm with running time roughly $O(k^{O(d)} n\log n)$ http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/pubs/pdf/small.pdf

Comment: @SashoNikolov is correct. Every n-vertex graph is the intersection graph of O(n)-dimensional unit hypercubes. Thus, in sufficiently high dimensions, this problem is equivalent to deciding whether a given graph contains a k-clique.

Comment: @Jeffε if you turn into a (sourced) answer, I'll be happy to accept!

Comment: Although I'm *also* interested in various heuristics used in practice.